# Understanding a recursive method I created

Tags: java

This is a pretty specific question but will hopefully help me understand recursion a bit further.

We were supposed to make a recursive method that printed out pascals triangle. After some time I finally got it working, but I still don't quite get how I got there.

```
public static int[] pascalLine(int order){
    // ska räkna ut n:te linjen i pascals triangel
    int [] arr = new int[order];
    if (order < 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value must be greater than 0");
    }
    else if(order == 1){
        return new int [] {1};
    }
    arr[0] = arr[order-1] = 1;
    int [] arrRev = pascalLine(order-1);
    System.out.println(toString(arrRev));
    for (int i = 1; i<arrRev.length; i++){
        arr[i] = arrRev[i-1] + arrRev[i];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I'm getting the entire triangle printed out up until line 5. What I don't understand is how this is possible. My thought process was that the method would call itself until it reaches 0 and give an exception.

But perhaps the first calling of the method (in main) is still going, while the other one has started (at the call inside the method) and this goes on until 1 (still don't understand why it doesn't reach zero though).

Comment: Just a comment, you should check `order` before you create the `int[] arr` with size `order`, you might get a `NegativeArraySizeException`.

Comment: Note: check `order` before you use it, and also, test for the case where it is *equal to* zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would only throw an exception if the initial call to `pascalLine` had a negative `order`.

```
else if(order == 1){
    return new int [] {1};
}
```

The recursion terminates when `order == 1`, so if you start with a positive `order`, you can never reach a negative `order`.

`pascalLine(order-1)` is only called if `order > 1`.